# Range of std::streambuf::sgetc

Tags: c++, stl

My code uses `std::streambuf::sgetc()` and `std::streambuf::sbumpc()` to read a file character by character. These functions return an int-typed value, which represents the read character if there is any, or is `EOF` if the end of file was reached. `EOF` is implementation-defined, and -1 in most implementations.

Can I ensure that, whenever a character is read (i.e. if the returned value is not -1) then the returned value is in the range [0 .. 255] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard *does not* guarantee this, but you'll probably be fine assuming that the result will be a valid `char`, because everyone does it that way.

If you want to be absolutely certain, use [`std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/to_char_type) to convert back to a `char`. Then, the standard *guarantees* that you receive the original value, which fits inside a `char`.

---

`std::streambuf` is essentially a shortcut for [`std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf). The integer type that `sbumpc()` and `sgetc()` return is the `int_type` of the this traits class.

The standard requires in [[char.traits.typedefs/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/char.traits#typedefs-2) that

> [f]or a certain character container type `char_­type`, a related container type `INT_­T` shall be a type or class which can represent all of the valid characters converted from the corresponding `char_­type` values, as well as an end-of-file value, `eof()`. The type `int_­type` represents a character container type which can hold end-of-file to be used as a return type of the iostream class member functions.

Basically, the `int_type` needs to hold all the possible characters, and a separate value for EOF.

Here is how the `std::streambuf` member functions are defined in [[streambuf.pub.get]](http://eel.is/c++draft/streambuf.pub.get):

> `int_type sbumpc();`
>
> *Returns*: If the input sequence read position is not available, returns `uflow()`. Otherwise, returns `traits​::​to_­int_­type(*gptr())` and increments the next pointer for the input sequence.
>
> ---
>
> `int_type sgetc();`
>
> *Returns*: If the input sequence read position is not available, returns `underflow()`. Otherwise, returns `traits​::​to_­int_­type(*gptr())`.

Ultimately, it comes down to how your standard library implements `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type`, and the standard has very few requirements on that (see Table 56 in [[char.traits.require]](http://eel.is/c++draft/char.traits#tab:char.traits.require)). It is at least *theoretically possible* that characters are mapped outside the range of the original char.

---

*However*, I am not aware of any library implementation that actually does this - most just use a larger integer type so they can return `-1` for EOF, but keep all the characters the same (it's also probably the most efficient way of implementing this). There is a reason that cppreference.com [explicitly mentions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/to_int_type) that

> a common implementation of `char_traits<char>::eof()` is `return -1`, and a corresponding valid implementation of `char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c)` is `return (unsigned char)c`.

I checked, and both stdlibc++ and libc++ do it that way. Unfortunately I couldn't check for MSVC, but I'd expect them to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation!